# Qt call to update not triggering call to paintEvent() while drawing data from serial port to scrollArea

Tags: qt

I am newbie to Qt 5.1.0. My problem with Qt is showed directly as follows. Data from serial port is received by readdata(), then call the draw() in mainwindow.cpp to deliver the data to newpaint() in paint.cpp. Two classes are created in this project:class mainwindow is mainly responsible for receiving data from serial port,class paint is for drawing the data (actually the data is coordinates of a mathematical function) on the scroll area widget which is on the mainwindow.

But in paint.cpp, paintevent is not invoked by update().UpdateEnabled() returns true depicting that the problem doesn't exist in the use of update().

Main part is pasted below.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    QPainterPath linepath;
    linepath.moveTo(0,0);
    ui->setupUi(this);
    paintwiget=new paint(linepath,ui->scrollArea);
    ui->scrollArea->setWidget(paintwiget);
    paintwiget->show();
    ui->closeserial->setEnabled(false);
    ui->sendData->setEnabled(false);

    serial=new QSerialPort(this);


     connect(serial,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readData()));


}


   void paint::newpaint(qreal *aa1, int len1)
   {
       if (!aa.isEmpty())
           aa.clear();
      int i;
      for (i=0;i<len1;i++)
          aa.append(aa1[i]);
     // qDebug()<<aa.size();
      //qDebug()<<"aa[0:3]"<<aa[0]<<" "<<aa[1]<<" "<<aa[2]<<" "<<aa[3];
          len=len1;
//          this->setVisible(true);
           qDebug()<<this->isVisible();//now returns true
          this->update();


          //qDebug()<<"okla";

   }
   void paint::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
   {
       qDebug()<<"ok~~";
       QPointF currentpoi;
       QPainter painter(this);
       int ii=0;
       qDebug()<<len;
       for (ii=0;ii<len/2;ii++)
       {
           currentpoi=path.currentPosition();
           qDebug()<<"currentpoi"<<currentpoi;
           path.moveTo(currentpoi);
           path.lineTo(aa[2*ii],aa[2*ii+1]);
      // painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
           painter.drawPath(path);
        }
   }
```

**paint.h**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTabWidget>
//#include <mainwindow.h>

class paint : public QWidget
{
public:
  explicit paint(QPainterPath &path,QWidget *parent=0);
void newpaint(qreal *,int);
QVector <qreal>aa;
int len;
QWidget *parent;

private:

  QPointF point;
 QPainterPath path;
protected:
 void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say for sure that this is the only issues you are facing, but there are at least three issues:

**Issue 1**

The following code tells me that you have a member of `MainWindow` called `paint * paintwiget`:

```
void MainWindow::draw(qreal *aa,int len)
{
    // ...
    paintwiget->newpaint(dist,len);
}
```

Then, this code tells me that you are **creating** a new temporary variable of the same name:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    // ...
    paint *paintwiget=new paint(linepath,ui->scrollArea->viewport());
}
```

The compiler should have probably given you a warning for this. Replace this line by:

```
paintwiget = new paint(linepath,ui->scrollArea->viewport());
```

(notice the lack of `paint *`), and tell me if this solves the problem.

**Issue 2**

You have to change this:

```
void paint::newpaint(qreal *aa, int len)
{
    // ...
    aa[i]=aa[i];
    len=len;
}
```

by this:

```
void paint::newpaint(qreal *aa_new, int len_new)
{
    // ...
    aa[i]=aa_new[i];
    len=len_new;
}
```

Otherwise, your `aa[i]=aa[i]` has no effect: it replaces the parameter of the method by itself, instead of replacing your member by the parameter of the method. Using a parameter with the same name than a member "hides" the member: you can't access it anymore, either at the left hand side or the right hand side of an assignment.

**Issue 3**

I'm not quite sure what you are doing with `scrollArea->viewport()` in the constructor of `paint`, but something tells me you are doing it wrong. The constructor of `paint` should NOT use it, but instead, you should do:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{    
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPainterPath linepath;
    paintwiget = new paint(linepath); // Do NOT pass viewport in parameter
    ui->scrollArea->setWidget(paintwiget);
    paintwiget->show();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I maybe ignored the warnings .Actually, paint *paintwiget is a member varible of the mainwindow class.In the constructor,paint *paintwiget is initialized as a subwiget of scrollArea (ps: class paint inherit from QWidget,the realization of the class paint is in another .cpp file called paint.cpp).My aim is to draw on the scrollarea.Apparently, this is not the key problem that made the drawing failed.But I will try your advice later after work.

Comment: @May: "Actually, paint *paintwiget is a member varible of the mainwindow class": yep, that what I said ;-) "In the constructor,paint *paintwiget is initialized as a subwiget of scrollArea": No, this is where you are wrong. If you do `paint *paintwiget = ...` then you declare and initialize a new temp variable (that happen to have the same name as your member) that is deleted at the end of the constructor. You have to do  `paintwiget = ...` instead to "initialize" the member. :-)

Comment: I finally understand what you mean. I know that widget is created invisible,so I wonder if it is possible to paint on invisible widgets. Although I have ui->scrollArea->show()  in constructor ( the qDebug()<<ui->scrollArea->isHidden() returns false),ui->scrollArea->isVisible returns false,too.How did that happen? I am really confused.

Comment: @May Have you tried what I propose then (removing `paint *`)? What was the result?

Comment: @May: Alright, then try this first when you have time, and I'm pretty confident this will unlock you so you will manage to find the potential other errors by yourself :-) (at least, `paint::newPaint()` will be called if `MainWindow::draw` is called.)

Comment: @May: Finally, I added other issues I could tell from the code submitted ;-)

Comment: It is kind of you to be so patient.I will let you know whether the modifications work later.

Comment: :I have tried what you said,the modifications above really take effects.PaintEvent() is triggered every time when update works.Other problems come out.In paint::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*),path.lineTo(aa[2*ii],aa[2*ii+1]) causes error information:                                      ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qvector.h, line 358
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.                           I am sure that size of aa is 4, and len equals 4 too.

Comment: By the way,I have updated my code and added the paint.h part for convenience.

Comment: Hi again @May :) I see that you printed debug information in `newPaint()` to check the size, I would suggest to do it in `paintEvent` too. Just before the loop, print `aa.size()`, `len`, `len/2`, and inside the loop, print `ii`, `2*ii` and `2*ii+1` and see if everything's correct here. Maybe your variable changed in the meantime for some reason. Also, as a general advice, for robustness, so not rely on different variables to be coherent. I would use instead `for(int i=0; i<aa.size()/2; i++) { aa[2*i], aa[2*i+1] }`

Comment: @May: or more conveniently, since you are using QtCreator, you can set up a *breakpoint* at the first line of `paintEvent()` (by clicking just left to the line number), so when you hit F5, it will execute your code in debug mode and stop at this point. Then you can see on the right column of QtCreator the values of all your variables, and navigate your code line by line using F10/F11, and see how the values evolve.

Comment: I tried qDebug()<<aa[0] in paintEvent yesterday,but got the same error information.I will try to work out the solution with the method you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you ,Boris.It turns out to be the incorrect use of QVector.My problem is solved now.